# PHP get object property not working, using Wordpress and JSON API plugin

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

I'm modifying the WP JSON API core to return just the post titles from a query result object, rather than all the other data.

```
$posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts($query);
$post_titles = array();
foreach ($posts as $post){
  $post_titles[] =  $post;          //result: {id:0, type:"post", title:"the title" ..}
  $post_titles[] =  $post['title']; //fail
}
```

When using `gettype($posts)` I get 'object', and I thought that `$obj['key'];` is how to get an object's property in PHP. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Object properties are referenced with `->`.

```
$post->title
```